# Can't import Play JSON using SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using this snippet to import Play JSON:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.0"
```

And getting this error. What I'm doing wrong?

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10: not found
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10: not found
unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1223)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1221)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1244)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1246)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1241)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1249)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1214)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1192)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10: not found
```

Comment: Your error had nothing to do with play-json. It can't load the scala library or compiler. What version of sbt are you using? Can you post the whole sbt output?

Comment: I'll make a wild guess here. You probably have scalaVersion :=  "2.10" somewhere in your sbt build. This is incorrect, you need to give a full semver as in  scalaVersion :=  "2.10.4"

Comment: @Jean, indeed. My bad.